# Read & split file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, io, split

I have a file in which my data is like:

```
1 [0,1, 4, 89]     
2 [3, 56, 6]     
3 [3,4,0]
```

And so on.

I'd like to read this file to access data line by line in my script so I try this to read my file and memorize it in a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        nb, list = line.split(' ')
        dictionary[nb] = list
```

Then I will do something like:

```
for e in dictionary:
    etc.
```

I have this error:

```
too many values to unpack
```

because I don't know how to deal with the second split element which is a list.

Is there an other way to access and work with any input file easily?

Comment: look at this, is what you get by spliting the line `['1', '[0,1,', '4,', '89]']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First at all, you can set a `maxsplit` argument of [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). From the document:

> `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1` elements). If maxsplit is not specified or `-1`, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

Demo:

```
>>> s = '1 [0,1, 4, 89]'
>>> s.split(' ', 1)
['1', '[0,1, 4, 89]']
>>> s.split(' ')
['1', '[0,1,', '4,', '89]']

>>> s.split(' ')[1]
'[0,1,'
>>> s.split(' ', 1)[1]
'[0,1, 4, 89]'
```

---

Then you need convert the *string of list* to a *real list*. I'd recommend use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). From the document:

> `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.

For example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = '1 [0,1, 4, 89]'
>>> s.split(' ', 1)[1]
'[0,1, 4, 89]'
>>> ast.literal_eval(s.split(' ', 1)[1])
[0, 1, 4, 89]
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(s.split(' ', 1)[1]))
<class 'list'>
>>> type(s.split(' ', 1)[1])
<class 'str'>
```

---

If you need remove the `\n` after the string, just use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). From the document:

> `str.strip([chars])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.

Use it like this:

```
>>> '   1 [0,1, 4, 89]   '.strip()
'1 [0,1, 4, 89]'
>>> '1 [0,1, 4, 89]\n'.strip()
'1 [0,1, 4, 89]'
>>>
```

It remove all tabs, newlines, spaces before and after the string, If you just want remove the spaces, newlines before or after the string, take a look at [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

---

So you can write your code like this:

```
import ast
dictionary = {}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(1)
        dictionary[key] = value
```

If you want the `dictionary`'s keys be int objects, just use `int()` function to convert it like:

```
import ast
dictionary = {}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        dictionary[int(key)] = value
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works :),

if I may, how to avoid /n at the end of lists ? I can't specified that values are integer (like we can do it easily for keys when we construct the dictionary).

Comment: @H.eyXD: Well, if an answer is helpful, remember mark it as accepted answer. Please check our [tour] and [help] for more details.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation and your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
import ast
d = dict()
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, l = line.split(' ', 1)
        d[k] = ast.literal_eval(l)

print(d)
```

it produces

```
{'3': [3, 4, 0], '1': [0, 1, 4, 89], '2': [3, 56, 6]}
```

In case you want the key to be an integer instead of a string just do

```
d[int(k)] = ast.literal_eval(l)
```

Comment: I can't do this because split() do not accept any argument (maybe because I'm working with python 2.7) ?

Comment: @H.eyXD - I've adjusted this question's tags to account for this information. You'll have to use one of the answers with `(' ', 1)`. Pynchia, I'd recommend `ast.literal_eval()` over `eval()` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 hey, mine was with `(' ', 1)`... I changed it because it looked nicer to explicitate the parameter name, as you did...  I'll change it back.... BTW, it wodl be great to know the python version beforehand

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thank you for the heads-up on `literal_eval`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `maxsplit` argument and `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
dictionary = {}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        nb, l = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        dictionary[nb] = ast.literal_eval(l)
```

Note that I've changed the name of the `list` to something that doesn't mask the built-in function `list()`, and used the default delimiter of any whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

For a save eval use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = {}
with open('file.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        key, rest = line.split(None, 1)
        data[key] = literal_eval(rest)


>>> data
{'1': [0, 1, 4, 89], '2': [3, 56, 6], '3': [3, 4, 0]}
```

From the docs:

> ```
> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
> ```
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.